# Determining the receive port or location for a message in BizTalk 2006

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2006

I need to know which receive port or location a given message was received through by either examining the name of the receive port/location, or populating a context property with either the name, or with some static string that I can define on each port/location

I will use this information in a custom disassembler to do some work on the message, but i need to know which port the message so that I know what kind of work I need to do to the message.  I'm pretty confident I know how to read context properties in a custom component like this, but I just can't figure out how to populate it earlier on.  And I can't figure out if the port a message came in on is noted anywhere on the message itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a nice list of the available context properties on [Abhilash's blog](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/abhilash/archive/2005/06/24/9017.aspx).

What you want is the ReceivePortName, so in your pipeline you would want something like:

```
public IBaseMessage Execute(IPipelineContext pContext, IBaseMessage pInMsg)    
{    
    IBaseMessageContext context = pInMsg.Context;
    string portName = context.Read("ReceivePortName", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties").ToString();
}
```